# Trouble with SceneBuilder 8.5.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: javafx, ubuntu-16.04, freeze, scenebuilder, gluon

I am having a problem running Gluon SceneBuilder 8.5.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I am presently using Java 8, and have downloaded and installed the latest 64-bit deb. I have also downloaded the executable jar and used that with the `java -jar` command in a terminal window, but the problem described below occurs whether the program is run from the installed shortcut or from the terminal.

I start SceneBuilder empty (with no project file open).  I can click through the various menus (File, View, Insert, Modify, Arrange, Preview, Window, Help) with no difficulty, and use the available functions in those menus.

However, as soon as I click the Edit menu, SceneBuilder freezes. After about 15 seconds, the SceneBuilder window darkens, and then returns (to normal brightness) after about 15 seconds. From the point of clicking the Edit menu and while the window is darkened, the entire computer is frozen.  When the SceneBuilder window returns, the computer is usable.  After several of these cycles, the Edit menu will appear. Clicking the Edit menu again causes the SceneBuilder window to go dark and not return.  The only option at this point is to click the X in the corner of the SceneBuilder window to force quit the program.

If I open a file with SceneBuilder, basically the same thing happens, I can use the menus (except for Edit).  However, if I click on any objects, like a button or container, the freezing cycle described above starts.

According to Help>About Scene Builder, there should a log file created in /tmp, but I don't find one there.  My java version is shown below:

```
 java version "1.8.0_191"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas what is going on?  Obviously, SceneBuilder is not usable like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something in the system (Java VM perhaps) became corrupted.  Just for the hec of it, I rebooted the PC, and SceneBuilder is working much better now!